# understanding data exchanges in MVC model(?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

thanks everyone for answering my questions, and special thanks to Mr.Paul for providing us with fantastic examples.
First of all, I'm not quite sure what I'm missing so chances are my title is misleading or not good. Feel free to correct it.

I'm trying to get a pagination using ajax. What I am showing there is a list of blogposts in the descending order. One view offers five entries, and by pressing the "next" icon, you can see another five. Really classic.

I'm completely new to programming in general, to say nothing of ajax, so I found  [this article](https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-search-by-document-type-and-property-in-umbraco/).

I'm having trouble understanding this part.
For the razor in _SearchForm.cshtml, he writes as follows:

```
@model CodeShare.Library.Models.SearchViewModel
@*@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("SubmitSearchForm", "Search", FormMethod.Post))*@

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitSearchForm", "Search", null, new AjaxOptions
{
 HttpMethod = "POST",
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
 UpdateTargetId = "search-results"
}))
{
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DocTypeAliases)
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FieldPropertyAliases)
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PageSize)
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PagingGroupSize)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchTerm, new { placeholder = "Search..." })
<button id="submit-button">Search</button>

<div id="search-results">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("RenderSearchResults", "Search", new { Model = Model.SearchResults });}
</div>
}
```

I kind of understand the basic structure here. He uses *Ajax.BeginForm* to call the necessary section, and when he calls that section, he renders it dynamically, passing down the search result as the parameter.

What I do not understand is :

1)how these values provided by *Html.HiddenFor* and *Html.TextBoxFor* are handed into Model.SearchResults.

2)this might be really basic, but could you tell me what these formats are..?
・m => m.PageSize
Is this called a lambda function? Why is this format frequently used in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **1)how these values provided by Html.HiddenFor and Html.TextBoxFor are**
>   **handed into Model.SearchResults.**

Since you are using an HTML form, any inputs contained in the form will be submitted when the form is submitted. When you use Html.HiddenFor and Html.TextBoxFor, you are generating inputs. So, when the form is submitted, those inputs are submitted as well. It's important to note that not all Razor helper functions do this. For example, Html.DisplayFor would not be submitted with the form since it does not generate an input. I suggest you read more on the [Html helper functions on the MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) and more on [form submission on W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html).

> **2)this might be really basic, but could you tell me what these formats
>   **are..? ・m => m.PageSize Is this called a lambda function? Why is this
>   **format frequently used in C#?**

Yes, that is a lambda expression. They're very useful for writing LINQ queries and other things. From a [basic article on DotNetPerls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda):

> A lambda expression describes a pattern. From mathematics, the lambda
>   calculus describes the world in patterns. In C# a lambda is a function
>   that uses clear and short syntax.

[Read more on lambda expressions on the MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).

Comment: Thanks for all the links and explanation.
>Since you are using an HTML form, ...   
I was completely oblivious of this. Thank you! I'll read the two articles you gave me.

Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! If you feel that I answered your question, you can mark it as best answer by clicking the check mark beside my answer. You can also click the uptick to upvote it. Generally, you should do this whenever you ask a question and get an answer you're happy with. Welcome to the community!